# Drop-Down Menu (Hovering)

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here.  I want a standard dropdown navigation block when someone hovers over a nav item (in this case the "Products" Link).  I haven't used an unordered list, just links.  I manage to get all the elements in the right place with the right formatting looks great.  The only issue is that I can't get the sub menu to show up when I hover over the main menu button?  Can't figure out why, it looks fine to me.  I'm previewing in google chrome

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>

      <title>Food Supply Company</title>

      <link href="FoodSupplyStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" text="text/css"> 

      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Volkhov:700" rel="stylesheet">  

  </head>

  <body>

     <div class="container">

      <div class="title">
        <h1>Food Supply Company</h1>
      </div>

        <div class="menunav">
            <a href="#" class="Products">Products</a>
            <a href="#">About Us</a>
            <a href="#">Contacts</a>
          </div>

        <div class="productsnav">
            <a href="#">Fruits</a>
            <a href="#">Vegetables</a>
            <a href="#">Dry Foods</a>
            <a href="#">Spices</a>
        </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

The CSS Style Sheet

```
*{
    Margin:0; 
    background-color: aliceblue;
    padding:0
}

.container{
    width: 900px;
    margin:auto;
    height:900px;

}

 h1{
    padding:20px 0px 10px 0px;
    background-color:bisque;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Verdana',sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size:50px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    color:coral;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px brown;
    Width: 100%;
    background-color:bisque;

}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'verdana', sans-serif;
    width:33%;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
    background-color: coral;
    color: bisque;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgb(40,0,0);
}

a:hover{
    font-family: 'verdana', sans-serif;
    background-color: bisque;
    color: coral;
}

.menunav a{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:5px
}

.productsnav{
    width:33%;
    margin-bottom:3px;
}

.productsnav a{
    width:100%;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.Products:hover .productsnav a{
    display:block;
}
```

The last few in the CSS code is what seems to be wrong, but I cannot figure out what exactly is amiss.  I have watched a number of videos on this and have formatted the css code to display the submenu in a few different ways but I could not figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use `ul` or `ol`.?

Answer (score 0):

You should really consider using unordered lists to make it easier to display your sub-menus.

I did a quick plunk of your problem without the other menu items.

https://plnkr.co/edit/pBtp39zKpRL5YqCZvxK0?p=preview

I changed your html and css to the following:

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <head>
      <title>Food Supply Company</title>
      <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" text="text/css"> 
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Volkhov:700" rel="stylesheet">  
  </head>

  <body>
     <div class="container">
      <div class="title">
        <h1>Food Supply Company</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="menunav">
        <ul>
          <li class="products">
            <a href="#">Products</a>
            <ul class="productsnav">
              <li><a href="#">Fruits</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Vgetables</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Dry Foods</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Spices</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
    Margin:0; 
    background-color: aliceblue;
    padding:0
}

.container{
    width: 900px;
    margin:auto;
    height:900px;

}

 h1{
    padding:20px 0px 10px 0px;
    background-color:bisque;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Verdana',sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size:50px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    color:coral;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px brown;
    Width: 100%;
    background-color:bisque;

}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'verdana', sans-serif;
    width:33%;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
    background-color: coral;
    color: bisque;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgb(40,0,0);
}

ul {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li a{
  width: 100%;
}

a:hover{
    font-family: 'verdana', sans-serif;
    background-color: bisque;
    color: coral;
}

.menunav a{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:5px
}

.productsnav{
    width:33%;
    margin-bottom:3px;
    display: none;
}

.productsnav a{
    width:100%;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.products:hover .productsnav{
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Please change it to the desired style.

Answer (score 0):

Yes thanks, I've done that now it looks much better.  The issue I have now is that when the sub menu pops up the next main menu item gets pushed to the bottom of the sub menu.  And also after the sub menu appears when I try to hover over it quickly disappears as soon as my mouse is removed off from the main nav item.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>

      <title>Food Supply Company</title>

      <link href="FoodSupplyStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" text="text/css"> 

      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Volkhov:700" rel="stylesheet">  

  </head>

  <body>

      <div class="container">

          <div class="title">
            <h1>Food Supply Company</h1>
          </div>

            <ul class="menunav">
              <ul class="Products">
                <li><a href="#" >Products</a>
                  <ul class="productsnav">
                    <li><a href="#">Fruits</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Vegetables</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Dry Foods</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Spices</a></li>
                    </ul></li></ul>
               <ul class="AboutUs">
                <li><a href="#" >About Us</a>
                  <ul class="aboutusnav">
                    <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Mission</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Personel</a></li>
                    </ul></li></ul>
               <ul class="Contact">
                <li><a href="#" >Contact</a>
                  </li></ul>
                </ul>





      </div>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
*{
    Margin:0;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    padding:0
}

.container{
    width: 900px;
    margin:auto;
    height:900px;

}

 h1{
    padding:20px 0px 10px 0px;
    background-color:bisque;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Verdana',sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size:50px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    color:coral;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px brown;
    Width: 100%;
    background-color:bisque;

}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'verdana', sans-serif;
    width:33%;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
    background-color: coral;
    color: bisque;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgb(40,0,0);
}

a:hover{
    font-family: 'verdana', sans-serif;
    background-color: bisque;
    color: coral;
}

li{
    list-style-type:none;
}

.menunav{
    margin-bottom:3px;
}

.menunav a{
    float:left;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-right:3px;
}

.productsnav, .aboutusnav{
    width:33%;
    margin-bottom:3px;
}

.productsnav a, .aboutusnav a{
    width:100%;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 5px;
  }

.Products:hover .productsnav a{
    display:block;
}

.aboutusnav{
    margin-left:33.3%;
 }

.AboutUs:hover .aboutusnav a{
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use CSS hover style for your drop-down menu then it must be a child item of hovered element.
Otherwise, you can use jQuery/javascript for this drop-down menu.
I have another idea to solve this problem. Please check this link:

```css
      *{
    Margin:0; 
    background-color: aliceblue;
    padding:0
}

.container{
    width: 900px;
    margin:auto;
    height:900px;

}

 h1{
    padding:20px 0px 10px 0px;
    background-color:bisque;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Verdana',sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size:50px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    color:coral;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px brown;
    Width: 100%;
    background-color:bisque;

}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'verdana', sans-serif;
    width:33%;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
    background-color: coral;
    color: bisque;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgb(40,0,0);
}

a:hover{
    font-family: 'verdana', sans-serif;
    background-color: bisque;
    color: coral;
}

.menunav a{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:5px
}

.productsnav{
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom:3px;
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
}
.Products{
  display:inline-block;
  width:33%;
  position:relative;
}
.Products a{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
}
.Products:hover .productsnav{
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>

      <title>Food Supply Company</title>

      <link href="FoodSupplyStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" text="text/css">

      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Volkhov:700" rel="stylesheet">  

  </head>

  <body>

     <div class="container">

      <div class="title">
        <h1>Food Supply Company</h1>
      </div>

        <div class="menunav">
            <div class="Products">
              <a href="#">Products</a>
              <div class="productsnav">
                  <a href="#">Fruits</a>
                  <a href="#">Vegetables</a>
                  <a href="#">Dry Foods</a>
                  <a href="#">Spices</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#">About Us</a>
            <a href="#">Contacts</a>
        </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

http://codepen.io/shiplo_R/pen/VPyMzp

Also, you can add some animation to show your drop-down menu smoothly instant of "display:none".

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this**

https://jsfiddle.net/uhg84d8d/

*HTML:*

```
    <html>
  <head>
      <title>Food Supply Company</title>
      <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" text="text/css"> 
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Volkhov:700" rel="stylesheet">  
  </head>

  <body>
     <div class="container">
      <div class="title">
        <h1>Food Supply Company</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="menunav">
        <ul>
          <li class="products">
            <a href="#">Products</a>
            <ul class="productsnav">
              <li><a href="#">Fruits</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Vgetables</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Dry Foods</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Spices</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href="#">Contacts</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

*CSS*

```
*{
    Margin:0; 
    background-color: aliceblue;
    padding:0
}

.container{
    width: 900px;
    margin:auto;
    height:900px;

}

 h1{
    padding:20px 0px 10px 0px;
    background-color:bisque;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Verdana',sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size:50px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    color:coral;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px brown;
    Width: 100%;
    background-color:bisque;

}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'verdana', sans-serif;
    width:33%;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
    background-color: coral;
    color: bisque;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgb(40,0,0);
}
    .menunav {
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
    }
.menunav ul {
  width:100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
}
.menunav ul li{
  list-style: none;
    float:left;
    width: 33.3%;
}
.menunav ul li a{
  width: 100%;
}

.menunav ul li a:hover{
    font-family: 'verdana', sans-serif;
    background-color: bisque;
    color: coral;
}

.menunav ul li a{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:5px
}

.menunav ul li .productsnav{
    width:33%;
    margin-bottom:3px;
    display: none;
}

.menunav ul li .productsnav li{
    width:100%;
    margin-top: 5px;
    float: left;
}
    .menunav ul li .productsnav li a{
    width:100%;
    margin-top: 5px;
    float: left;
}

.menunav ul li.products:hover .productsnav{
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
}
```

**Then it will work...:)**